# Is there a keyboard shortcut to save edited layers from the digitize toolbar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shortcuts

I need to do a lot of manual editing of existing layers in QGIS. To do so, we use tools from the `digitize toolbar`. Since we go back and forth between a bunch of layers, we need to save every single edit, so a keyboard shortcut would be useful. I looked at the [editing page for the digitize toolbar](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#saving-edited-layers), but I couldn't find an answer there.

Is there a way to save edits via a keyboard shortcut while digitizing existing layers in QGIS?
I'm using version 3.16.11 (Hannover) and a Windows interface.

Comment: Thanks all, I was searching in vain for the `settings` toolbar but discovered it was called `Extra` in my QGIS version/language settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a new keyboard shortcut :

- Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> ► <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts…</kbd>
- Search for `Save Layer Edits` and assign a keyboard shortcut.

Documentation for Keyboard Shortcuts for QGIS `3.16` [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#shortcuts) (and newer if you change the version).

Comment: *(and newer if you change the version)* probably for me @_@

Answer (score 7):

If you go to Settings>Keyboard Shortcuts you are able to set or modify shortcut for lots of action including "Save Layer Edits"

[image]